# ASP.NET MVC3 - textarea with @Html.EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have ASP.NET MVC3 app and I have also form for add news. When VS2010 created default view I have only text inputs for string data, but I want to have textarea for news text. How I can do it with Razor syntax.

Text input look like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text)
```

Comment: Related, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10696647/419956) to another question about how to customize that EditorTemplate.

Answer (score 383, accepted):

You could use the [`[DataType]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute.aspx) attribute on your view model like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

and then you could have a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }
}
```

and a view which does what you want:

```
@model AppName.Models.MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Text)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: Pretty much what I was looking for, but what if I need to specify the rows and cols html attributes?

Comment: I am still getting [class="text-box single-line"] at the source code :(

Comment: Extremely knowledgeable and still keeping it as simple as it gets and explains everything step by step. hail @Darin Dimitrov.

Comment: @Jason use CSS for styling.

Answer (score 139):

Someone asked about adding attributes (specifically, 'rows' and 'cols'). If you're using Razor, you could just do this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Text, new { cols = 35, @rows = 3 })
```

That works for me. The '@' is used to escape keywords so they are treated as variables/properties.

Comment: Indeed - if you know your want a text area with cols/rows, there is little reason to use EditorFor instead of TextAreaFor. Anyone have a reason you'd still need to use EditorFor and know you need to specify cols/rows?

Answer (score 98):

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Text)
```

Comment: I like this method better because the popular answer here involves modifying the database model, which means you have to drop and recreate the underlying database if using EntityFramework.

Comment: That DataType Annotation does not force a refresh in Entity Framework.

Comment: @Ciaran: This statement should ring a bell. There should never be any need to change the database layer to modify the UI. There should be a presentation object, which is mapper to the database object. Never use the database object in ur UI.

Comment: To be clear, what Frederik is referring to is creating classes that represent your view data SEPARATE from classes that are used in your DbContext. Don't pass your DbContext models into views. Create a view model class, then shift the info you care about from the db model into the view model, and vice versa when accepting inputs.

Comment: @FrederikPrijck I don't disagree, but doesn't that violate the DRY principal? You have to copy all the properties from one class to another class. Is there a less "mundane" of doing it, that you have found?

Comment: @JamesHaug The cons of this duplication are outweighed by its pros. If mapping is your concern, there are tools like AutoMapper that can help.

Answer (score 4):

Declare in your Model with

```
  [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
  public string urString { get; set; }
```

Then in .cshtml can make use of editor as below. you can make use of  **@cols** and **@rows**  for TextArea size

```
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.urString, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "",@cols = 35, @rows = 3 } })
```

Thanks !