# How can I create more than one editor template for a multi-line textbox in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

I have the following two types of multiline textareas in my views:

```html
<textarea cols="100" rows="15" class="full-width" id="dialogText" 
          name="Text">@Model.Text</textarea>

<textarea cols="100" rows="10" class="full-width" id="dialogText" 
          name="Text">@Model.Text</textarea>
```

I would like to take advantage of custom editor templates, but keep the ability to specify attributes differently (e.g. the `rows` are different between the two above).

Is it possible for me to declare and use two different kinds of templates for the same field? If so then how should I declare the template and how do I specify the different templates to use?

Also how can I declare the different cols and rows. Can I use cols,rows or should I specify height and width in `CSS` such as `width=500px, height=600px` or `400px`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could override the [default editor template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MultilineText.cshtml`):

```
@Html.TextArea(
    "", 
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue.ToString(),
    ViewData
)
```

and then assuming you have defined a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

inside the main view you could do this:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Text, new { cols = "100", rows = "15", id = "dialogText", @class = "full-width" })
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Text, new { cols = "100", rows = "10", id = "dialogText", @class = "full-width" })
```

which will render the expected output:

```
<textarea class="full-width" cols="100" id="dialogText" name="Text" rows="15">
    hello world
</textarea>

<textarea class="full-width" cols="100" id="dialogText" name="Text" rows="10">
    hello world
</textarea>
```

Also you could *enhance* the editor template so that you don't need to specify the @class attribute at every EditorFor call like this:

```
@{
    var htmlAttributes = ViewData;
    htmlAttributes["class"] = "full-width";

}
@Html.TextArea(
    "", 
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue.ToString(),
    htmlAttributes
)
```

and now you could:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Text, new { cols = "100", rows = "15", id = "dialogText" })
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Text, new { cols = "100", rows = "10", id = "dialogText" })
```

Oh and don't forget that ids must be unique in HTML so this `id = "dialogText"` should obviously be different for the second textarea.

Comment: Thank you Darin. I will review and test out all you have said and mark as answered when I've had the chance to test it out. As always your answer was very detailed. Just one quick question. Do you think it is okay to use the cols and rows or should I specify the width in px. If it was px then how could I do that?

Comment: Both are possible. I am not a CSS specialist but I have heard from my friends designers that they prefer to use CSS for this. So use the style property: `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Text, new { style = "width: 100px; height: 50px;" })`. Or apply a predefined CSS class.

Comment: This solution doesn't look like its possible until version 6. https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/965

Answer (score 3):

you can create an editor template `MultiLine1.cshtml` and `MultiLine2.cshtml` and in your view model you can use `UIHint` to specify which editor template you want to use for that particular property. But you can specify only one template for one property. On different properties of same type, you can use different templates though.