# creating textarea with htmlhelper in asp .net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, textarea, html-helper

USING : ASP .NET MVC 4 
in one of my page i need a **textarea** with a certain width and height using **html helper class**. some of my code is given below :

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MailSubject)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MailSubject)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MailSubject)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MailBody)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MailBody)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MailBody)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field1">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
    </div>
```

I am wondering how I define the size(width/hide) of the **editorfor(model.content)**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119221/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-a-multi-line-editor-field

Comment: You need height of editorfor to set ? or do you need to use textarea and set its height and width ?

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi, thanks. Can defining col/rows can be responsive?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695983/how-can-i-create-more-than-one-editor-template-for-a-multi-line-textbox-in-mvc3

Answer (score 5):

I realize this question is over a year old but just in case anyone is looking for the answer, here it is:

```
Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Field, new { rows = "", cols = "", style = "width: 90%; height: 50px;" })
```

You can either apply the styles inline or use the class declaration.  This will render the textarea on the page like so:

```
<textarea class="swiper-no-swiping" name="model.Field" cols="" rows="" style="width: 90%; height: 50px;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. I'm a newb, so I'm not really sure, but using the following I was able to adjust the height...

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.FullItinerary, 20, 10, null)
```

I still don't know how to adjust width, my current google mission...

Answer (score 0):

Write a customer helper, or extend the functionality of the TextAreaFor helper.

Here is a resource to help you create a custom helper: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/writing-custom-html-helpers-for-asp.net-mvc/