# Html.EditorFor How to set bootstrap class and HTML attributes?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to build a input text area with bootstrap styling and some HTML custom attributes. Here is my code:

```
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments, new { style = "color: red; width: 400px", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter detailed comments..."), type = "text" })
```

My model data comes from a viewmodel with the following data annotation:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Comments{ get; set; }
```

Unfortunately this doesn´t work as I works if it´s a TextBoxFor. The EditorFor does not get styled, showing on sceen a plain small default HTML.

I wish to know how can I solve that ? I´m using MVC4 and I cannot move to MVC5.1 for now (it´s a requirement. I know MVC5.1 has some improvements on that area).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the `MultilineText` attribute I presume you want a textarea?  You could just simply change the `EditorFor` call to `TextAreaFor`:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments, new { style = "color: red; width: 400px", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter detailed comments..."), type = "text" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the [default editor template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MultilineText.cshtml`):

```
<someboostraphtmlelements>
@Html.TextArea(
    "", 
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue.ToString(),
    ViewData
)
</someboostraphtmlelements>
```

This is shamelessly stolen from [Darin Dimitrov Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10696647/209259) to a similar question.